# Pump like solenoid but more powerful?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, biomedical-engineering

Is there any pump available which can suck the water just like solenoid pump ( which means i can just put the input pipe in water and it will suck the water and get it out unlike DC motor pump which have to be submurged in water, which is not feasible for my project) but the good pressure is also needed.
I am thinking about piston pump but i am not being able to understand if it's going to work with my project or not.

In my project,i have a jug of water from which i want to get the water and send it to other but I can't submerge the motor in water all the time.

Comment: use a syphon to connect to the pump which can then be on the table...

Comment: @SolarMike I can't use a syphon because it's not so strong and not feasible as it will have to be on top and the second jug have to be on bottom which is going to make our machine so long.

Comment: The energy loss in a syphon is basically due to pipe friction as the height up is offset by the distance down if they are equal. You should show a diagram of your layout which will stop people wasting time guessing....

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a Diaphraghm pump. These are self-priming, like solenoid pumps, and come in a wide range of sizes.

How far above the water is the highest point in your system compared to the jug? And what volume flow rate do you require?